# flutter -Is it secure to save Json config file as assets in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on an app, and I want to know what is the best way to store the config file. Now, I am planning to use a JSON file and save it as assets. However, the file is important，it should not be accessed by others.

Comment: What config file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am an expert in CyberSecurity and I have some considerations to say. The first is that it is impossible for you to totally prevent an attacker from having access to sensitive information, all you can do is make it difficult, often to the point that it takes years to succeed, but there is nothing 100% safe from reverse engineering.

The second consideration is: There is only one way that will give the attacker data from the tray, and it can be considered the most vulnerable way to save sensitive data: Save to assets, in a json file. It seems ironic that you mention it.

Json is the most human-readable language that exists (and it is impossible to lose this position, read a file in quotes and its value with: it is intuitive even for those who do not program), if it is in the assets folder, it will be a file totally unprotected after compilation, which can be extracted without decompiling the apk, just using any file roller. This is practically saying: look and read my file, I'm begging you for it.

Sensitive data must be stored on the android on the keystore, and on iOS on the Keychain. There is a Flutter plugin that abstracts this for you (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage).

As a specialist in CyberSecurity, I need to tell you that even storing like this, you will not be 100% safe, in fact, security of this level does not exist.
But what I recommend that will at least take some work and eliminate 99% of the people who are looking to break your app, is:

Convert json to String, and save it in encrypted FSS, without plain text. When you need the file, take the generated string, decrypt it, and turn it back into json.
Remembering that the encryption key must also be stored, or if you are going to put it in your code, don't do it with plain text, encrypt it beforehand, or at least convert it to base64 (this is not security, it will only make literal searches difficult) , and finally, don't use words like 'token', 'secure', 'secret' as a key, because those are the first words searched. Test something completely unusual, I used magnolia until one of these days (and I'm counting here because I changed).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This is the answer I expected. Can I ask another question, I am still using sqlite and hive database. How can it be safely stored? I want to use icloud to synchronize data between different devices, so I may not be able to put them in FSS

Comment: Use Hive's encrypted box, and store the box's key in FSS. To generate the keys, Hive has a function that does this automatically, however, you will not be able to place it directly in the FSS, because it requires a string. You will have to convert bytedata to string to store, and then do the reverse to decrypt the key before inserting it into Hive's encrypted box.
Before opening the box, first obtain the FSS key, open the box with the key, and use it normally.
Just be careful with the name of your keys on Hive too, the encrypted box only encrypts the value, the key remains the same.